# Issue using the “count” Parameter in the new Twitter Search API 1.1

Tags: twitter

I am having issues including the count parameter in the new Twitter Search API (Version 1.1) query. If I execute the query without the “count” parameter, I obtain the 15 default results. Meanwhile, if I include the count parameter, I obtain a 401 Unauthorized Error.

You will find hereafter, partial extracts from my code in C#.

1) Initially, the end of the baseString variable is set to “q=Test&count=100”.

2) After passing the baseString variable to the EscapeDataString function, the end becomes q%3DTest%26count%3D100, formatted in percent encoding, as expected.

3) Finally, the resource_url submitted is the following:
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=Test&count=100

```
var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";

var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&q={6}&count={7}";

var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
oauth_consumer_key,
oauth_nonce,
oauth_signature_method,
oauth_timestamp,
oauth_token,
oauth_version,
Uri.EscapeDataString(q),
Uri.EscapeDataString(count)
);

baseString = string.Concat("GET&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));



var postBody = "q=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(q) + "&count=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(count);
resource_url += "?" + postBody;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
```

Would anyone have an idea why I am receiving this 401 Error?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, it seems when you Generate OAuth signature Twitter is fussy about the format of this string. I found even re-ordering the variables cause authentication errors.
Try replacing the specific lines in your code with the re-ordered ones below, hope that helps.

```
var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
var tweet_query = "Test";
var tweet_count ="5";

var baseFormat = "count={7}&oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&q={6}";

var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
oauth_consumer_key,
oauth_nonce,
oauth_signature_method,
oauth_timestamp,
oauth_token,
oauth_version,
Uri.EscapeDataString(tweet_query),
Uri.EscapeDataString(tweet_count)
);



var postBody = string.Format("q={0}&count={1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(tweet_query), Uri.EscapeDataString(tweet_count));
```

Answer (score 0):

@JF0001

yes i have the same issue, but johnHk already have the correct answer. it's just placement issue.

when i use this, it doesn't work :

base_Format = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" + "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&q={6}&result_type={7}&count={8}"

but if i use this, it's work :

base_Format = "count={8}&oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" + "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&q={6}&result_type={7}"

look at the "count=" parameter, haha just re-order it into the first place.